# Ubuntu 23.10 - No running apps on top bar

Tags: gnome-shell, 23.10

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10, currently running applications are no longer visible on top bar. Is it a bug or feature?

Opera and terminal in this case:

[image: Opera and terminal]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature, not a bug. The Gnome Shell developers have retired the application menu in Gnome Shell 45.

Comment: any extension which returns it back ?

Comment: @overflowed You can use this [Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/) to get the Application menu

Comment: nope,doesn't work

Comment: @overflowed Indeed, that is not an appropriate extension. However, I was able to locate at least two extensions that bring back the application menu on the gnome Shell website in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: @overflowed, I misunderstood the question and mentioned a different extension. By the way, the extension in your answer works well!

Answer (score 0):

"[App menu is back](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6433/app-menu-is-back/)" extension shows currently running apps, took me some time to find it.

[image: screenshot-of-running-app]